# How to write one line between two lines?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, text

[image: How can I write text like this in LaTex]
How can I write text like this in LaTex.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What about `tabular` and `\multirow`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
I want to do something similar.  There is some text.   There is some text.

\qquad I have one sentence here 
\begin{tabular}{l}
  Outcome one\\
  Outcome two
\end{tabular}

And then my passage moves on.  There is some text.   There is some text.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

As separate paragraphs, and then as a single paragraph.  Note that stacked material will not linebreak.  It was not clear from the question if this is an issue.

The `\stackanchor` produces the vertically split text, while the `\addstackgap` adds vertical buffer above/below the stack.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\def\stackalignment{l}
\begin{document}
I want to do something similar.  There is some text.   There is some text.

\qquad have one sentence here \addstackgap[5pt]{\stackanchor[8pt]{Outcome one}{Outcome two}}

And then my passage moves on.  There is some text.   There is some text.


\bigskip
I want to do something similar.  There is some text.   There is some text.
have one sentence here \addstackgap[5pt]{\stackanchor[8pt]{Outcome one}{Outcome two}}
And then my passage moves on.  There is some text.   There is some text.
\end{document}
```

[image]