# How to achieve independent 2 columns

Tags: formatting

I want to have something that looks like this:
[image]

But I'm not sure how to get it as the left column should have 2 rows and the right 4 rows. So I want the two to be independent.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Could you add some minimal working code ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). See: [How to write one line between two lines?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/362624/124842)An option could be [a multirow table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/73285/124842),  [Table with multiple lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/40562/124842) or [How to add a forced line break inside a table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/176780/124842).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{array,xcolor,multirow}
\colorlet{darkred}{red!80!black}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{rl}
    \multirow{2}{*}{\huge\bf Hello} & {\color{darkred}\bf text\ldots}\\
                                    & {\color{darkred}\bf text\ldots}\\
    \multirow{2}{*}{\huge\bf World!!} & {\color{darkred}\bf text\ldots}\\
                                      & {\color{darkred}\bf text\ldots}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Accepting without voting up is counter-intuitive behavior, at least from my point of view.

Comment: OP hasn't enough reputation to vote.